# Array of strings "subscripted" by an enum in C#

Tags: c#

This is a hang over from my Delphi days where I was able to do something as follows:

```
  type
   TCars  = (Ford, Nissan, Toyota, Honda);     
  const
      CAR_MODELS = array[TCars] of string = ('Falcon','Sentra','Camry','Civic');
```

which allowed me to an enumeration declartively with some associated data. In this case a string but it could have been a record structure or similair. It meant that if I added a member to TCars and forgot to update the CAR_MODELS array I would get a compile time error.

What is the C# approach to this? I have tried:

```
public enum ReportFileGeneratorFileType
{
    Excel,
    Pdf,
    Word
}

string[ReportFileGeneratorFileType] myArray = {"application/vnd.ms-excel", "application/pdf", "application/vnd.ms-word"};
```

but that does not appear to compile.

Comment: I don't think `c#` has something that will give you an error if you don't update a description.

Comment: C# has no string based enumeration that will be checked on compile time. The suggestion to use a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> is probably your best bet, however this will be created at runtime

Comment: You can keep descriptions defined declaratively on the enum itself. This doesn't give compile-time errors, but minimizes such mistakes.

Comment: @JacekGorgoń Yes but if I wanted to add additional information then I would not be able to. Idea here is that I may also say want to add the file extension to the enum as well as say the mime type encoding.

Comment: Actually, this would be trivial to extend, either by extending the single attribute to hold more values or by adding a new attribute, depending on the context. In fact, it seems more extensible than the Delphi approach.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Dictionary<key, value>` as

```
var myArray = new Dictionary<ReportFileGeneratorFileType, string>();
myArray[ReportFileGeneratorFileType.Excel] = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
```

Comment: Unfortunately that code has to then be maintained when I add a member to ReportFileGeneratorFileType which is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an attribute (custom or built-int, such as DisplayNameAttribute) over the enum values to give them associated names/values. Example custom attribute follows:

```
public class ContentTypeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public ContentTypeAttribute(string contentType) 
    { 
         ContentType = contentType;
    }
}

public enum ReportFileGeneratorFileType
{
    [ContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel")]
    Excel,

    [ContentType("application/pdf")]
    Pdf,

    [ContentType("application/vnd.ms-word")]
    Word
}
```

To retrieve the content type based on an enum value, use:

```
...
ReportFileGeneratorFileType myType = ...
string contentType = myType.GetType()
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ContentTypeAttribute))
    .Cast<ContentTypeAttribute>()
    .Single()
    .ContentType;
...
```

This may seem kind of complicated, but lets you keep content types (or whatever data) right on the enum itself, so you're not likely to forget adding it after adding a new type.

Comment: Note that the retrieval can be optimized significantly; this is just a basic approach written from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

In `c#` you can [use `Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), using this namespace

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

You can add `Description` attribute to your enum elements

```
public enum ReportFileGeneratorFileType
{
    [Description("application/vnd.ms-excel")]
    Excel,
    [Description("application/pdf")]
    Pdf,
    [Description("application/vnd.ms-word")]
    Word
}
```

And [using these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16888620/340760) you can "extract" a `Dictionary<ReportFileGeneratorFileType, string>` from your enum and use it on your code.

Comment: Implementing this takes 3 minutes and gives reasonable assurance the author seeks.

Comment: Well, yes... He probably won't need this much trouble, but it can be done. For someone new to c# might consume sometime, but to use after that it will be easy :)

Comment: I've used this approach before, but I had to discard it when trying to do internationalization and localization because it gets far too fiddly then.

Comment: The actual values here suggests it's MIME-type or at least something not influenced by locale. Also, hardcoded dictionaries won't be useful when localizing either.

Comment: @BrunoLM Writing the extension methods to create the dictionary is a novel idea. And I guess extended with generics so that if I also wanted to store say FileSize (int) and FileExtension (string) I could create additional attributes I could store all of this in a struct in the dictionary. 

For sure adding the attributes will mean it is less easy to forget to add all the "additional info" when a new member is added. This is still however not a compile time check and would be rather cumbersome. The Delphi approach is so much cleaner, elegant and way less code :-)